# Where to place my button to open a full screen gallery in my design on iOS?

Tags: buttons, actions

I need advice to placing a button or an icon on my design. The button/icon should open a full screen gallery. I have a few ideas mock already like press the image or press a button.

The problem with this 2 ideas is in booth test cases the user is always confused and doesn't really know how to open the gallery.

I am looking for any suggestion's

here's the mockup
[image]

Comment: By gallery do you mean there is more than one picture or just a zoom of the one shown? Because if there is more than one it should really be signified somewhere.

Comment: That image is just a thumbnail image of more images and yes they are more images. the action open's a full gallery

Answer (score 1):

The best example I can think of is Youtube. Though it's not video, but can work really well in the case of image gallery as well. The bottom bar can be used to show the current position in the gallery and allow users to click on either image or the button at bottom right corner to enlarge the image and enter the full-screen gallery view mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your case reminds me CNN's app, and here's the suggestion:

[image: CNN's example]

As soon as the users enters the screen an icon of a camera (with the number of pictures on the gallery) appears. This icon vanishes after a few seconds thus leaving the image clear. If the user taps on the image, the user will be send to the gallery (last image on the right).

On the gallery you can add a little description and/or the image counter at the foot (or corner if it is just the counter) of the screen leaving the image clear instead of the middle as CNN does it.